# Jquery Autocomplete list hide when going to select it

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I am using jquery auto-complete in my code, data binding is working properly but when i am going to mouse over to select list it goes to hide. This is code where i am using it

```
  $("input#TextBoxLoincCode").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: GetSiteRoot() + "ws/wsNotifications.asmx/BindProblemList",
            data: "{ 'SearchText': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.ProblemCode,
                        ShortName: item.ShortName,
                        Id: item.Id
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (e, i) {
        $(this).val(i.item.Name);
    },
    open: function () {
        test();
        $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({
            "width": 400
        });
       $(this).autocomplete('widget').zIndex(100002);            
    }
});
```

Comment: I think mouse over style needs to be change

Answer (score 0):

There was a jquery version conflict issue. I have remove older version and add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs /jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```